# How can two backward merges be combined?

Tags: git

I am using a git workflow with a develop branch and multiple feature branches. Sometimes a feature branch needs to be updated to the latest state in develop, using a backward merge. Rarely, two backward merges are done in a row (develop having received new commits between the merges).

Sometimes it makes sense to combine the two merges to simplify the history, ideally without redoing all of the actual merging work. How can this be done? For normal commits I would use `git rebase HEAD^^ --interactive` and mark the latter commit as `fixup`, but in the case of merge commits this shows all of the commits brought in by the merges.

Comment: what is a backward merge? Instead of merging develop into your feature branch, you merge your incomplete feature branch into develop?

Comment: Backward merge is develop being merged into the feature branch. It's backward because usually you only merge feature branches into develop.

Comment: OK.... now I see where the name came from. Let me see if I have enough stuff to provide you with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.... what you are doing is technically possible.... say, you just noticed you have 2 backward merges in a row and would like to get them squashed into a single merge.... in a single shot, that can be done, like this (assuming you are working on the feature branch):

```
git checkout -b test $( git commit-tree -p HEAD~2 -p origin/develop -m "Merging develop" ${HEAD^tree} )
```

There you created (and checked out) a test branch that has the same working tree as your HEAD revision and has your feature branch - 2 revisions (in other words, the last revision before the 2 backward merges) and the tip of develop. This way, you got what you wanted, you didn't have to redo any merge (and no merge conflicts).

**However** when working with feature branches, there's no need to do *backward* merges.... it's much better (if you ask me) to get straight stories for feature branches and for that you should *rebase* instead of merge. You have 3 revisions.... develop moved? You rebase, you sill get your 3 revisions one after the other.... you write 2 more revisions, develop moves? You rebase again, you *still* get your 5 revisions one after the other. This simplifies a lot of work in terms of seeing what development was all about *and* also has advantages if you want to move that development on top of other branches, like a backport, por example.

Comment: Pretty cool, I ended up doing git reset --hard $( git commit-tree HEAD^{tree} -p HEAD~2 -p origin/develop -m "<merge message>" ) to get it all done in one step. Previously always had to do a dance of soft and hard resets to get this result. 

Rebasing is good, but it's a different tool and not always applicable, e.g. if you want to preserve pushed history or if it would break the buildability of your older commits.

Comment: There are some cases where the usual commands fall short and we have to pull the big guns, like `git commit-tree` witch is a plumbing command. Very powerful tool if used wisely... probably the biggest hurdle there is understanding how git pieces revisions together (like, inner workings)

Comment: That's fine.... the only thing I would say is that as your feature branch is in _development_ and as long as it hasn't been merged in development branch, there's probably no real need to be strict in terms of keeping the history of that branch. Just saying.